# How to write shorter Python code with several if and else statements?

Tags: python

How can you optimize the following code and write less?

```
  class CleanItem():

     def process_item(self, item, spider):

        PSCV = str(item['page_source_canonical']).split("'")[1]

        if PSCV != "":
            if PSCV != item['page_source']:
                item['page_source_canonical_is_itself'] = False
            else:
                item['page_source_canonical_is_itself'] = True
        else:
                item['page_source_canonical_is_itself'] = True

    
        return item
```

First it checks if it is empty. If it is empty, it is true. If it is not empty it should be checked and if it is the same then again it is true. otherwise it is false.

Comment: `PSCV in ("", item['page_source'])` gives you your desired boolean value directly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You wrote

```
        if PSCV != "":
            if PSCV != item['page_source']:
                item['page_source_canonical_is_itself'] = False
            else:
                item['page_source_canonical_is_itself'] = True
        else:
                item['page_source_canonical_is_itself'] = True
```

You want

```
        item['page_source_canonical_is_itself'] =  PSCV in (
            '', item['page_source'])
```

That's [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself), and
very clearly spells out Author's Intent
that we shall assign True upon matching either value,
else False.

---

Style nit: [PEP 8](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/#naming-conventions) asks that you spell it `pscv`, lowercase.

---

Consider deleting the unused `spider` parameter.

Comment: What is this operator called? and do you have an educational resource?

Comment: I think you're referring to the `in` operator: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#in Also, linter documentation is here: https://flake8.pycqa.org/en/latest/

Comment: the "in" operator is used to check if an element is found in an iterable e.g a list, tuple. Here it is checking if PSCV is '' or item['page_source']

Comment: @J_H Can you help with this question? https://stackoverflow.com/q/73389010/8519380

Comment: @zaki98's use of `return request.replace(...)` seems pretty relevant.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you could simplify

```
if PSCV != "":
    if PSCV != item['page_source']:
        item['page_source_canonical_is_itself'] = False
    else:
        item['page_source_canonical_is_itself'] = True
else:
    item['page_source_canonical_is_itself'] = True
```

to

```
if PSCV != "" and PSCV != item['page_source']:
    item['page_source_canonical_is_itself'] = False
else:
    item['page_source_canonical_is_itself'] = True
```

or even further to

```
condition = PSCV != "" and PSCV != item['page_source']
item['page_source_canonical_is_itself'] = not condition
```

Comment: Or shorter... `item['page_source_canonical_is_itself'] = PSCV == "" or PSCV == item['page_source']`

Comment: @OneCricketeer That is indeed even shorter, but also 4 characters above the maximum line length of 79, as recommended by PEP

Comment: How about? `= PSVC in ("", item['page_source'])`

Comment: Good one, was also thinking about that, but I'd argue it's a tad bit less intuitive

Answer (score 1):

```
 if PSCV != "":
        if PSCV != item['page_source']:
            item['page_source_canonical_is_itself'] = False
        else:
            item['page_source_canonical_is_itself'] = True
    else:
            item['page_source_canonical_is_itself'] = True
```

If I wanted to refactor the code above, two options

1. The most explanatory (not necessarily the shortest)

   ```
     if (PSCV == ""):
           item['page_source_canonical_is_itself'] = True
     elif (PSCV == item['page_source']):
           item['page_source_canonical_is_itself'] = True
     else:
           item['page_source_canonical_is_itself'] = False
   ```
2. The shorter - ternary

   ```
    item['page_source_canonical_is_itself'] = ( (PSCV == "") or (PSCV == item['page_source']) )? true: false
   ```